# Leibniz rule for vector fields

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

There are Leibniz rules for
$\nabla(fg),\nabla\cdot(f\textbf{G}),\nabla\times(f\textbf{G})$ and all can be proved by coordinate expansion (not so tedious).

I wonder whether there are Leibniz rules for $\nabla(\textbf{F}\cdot\textbf{G}),\nabla\cdot(\textbf{F}\times\textbf{G}),\nabla\times(\textbf{F}\times\textbf{G})$. It seems that none of them holds when I test by Mathematica. If so, are there formulas to expand these ones?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Product_rules

Comment: Bravo@_@Thank you so much~